# Cefsharp use more than 1 seconds to parse dom content?

Tags: cefsharp

I use CefSharp 88.2.90. When loading URL for the first time, after the browser is created, it takes from 1 seconds pending.
however, when I use chrome to load the same url, this pennding dose not occur

[image]

Comment: Are you comparing to chrome version 88? The performance is basically tied to chromium version, in short upgrading/downgrading the chrome version will almost always produce different performance characteristics.

Comment: yes, even more, I try 89.0.170 and 87.1.132, it still happen

Comment: You can download and test with the CEF Sample application, details are at https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#cefsharp-vs-chromium-embedded-frameworkcef

Comment: I noticed that when chrome startup, it creates 8 instances, however, my application only use 2 instance.

Comment: Site isolation trials are currently disabled as there are some bugs in the chromium embedded framework, https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/89/CefSharp.Core.Runtime/CefSettingsBase.h#L55 you can remove this at runtime. Run chrome with --disable-site-isolation-trials for a comparison

Comment: yes, I think that's the problem. when I remove disable-site-isolation-trials, it's much quicker than before. thank you!

Comment: Be aware there's a reason it's disabled see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/2967#issuecomment-618024248